# VBA Copy specific range in multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first attempt to write vba code. I have a excel workbook with 19 worksheets (FVal.xls), each of them composed of 130 rows and 15 columns with data.

If I find a specific value ("Fla") in the fourth column, I want to copy data in this row from column 10 to column 15  and  paste it in row 3, columns 10 - 15 in each sheet.

Code is running but it leaves blank cells in the position of copied cells.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FinCop()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As integer

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\FVal.xls")

For Each ws In wb1.Worksheets

i = 1
Do While ws.Cells(i, 4).Text <> "Fla"
i = i + 1
Loop

ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 10), ws.Cells(i, 15)).Copy
ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, 7), ws.Cells(3, 15)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, _
                    SkipBlanks:=True, _
                    Transpose:=False
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: you are missing `Loop` to close your `Do While ws.Cells(i, 4).Text <> "Fla"` , you need to add it before `Next ws` line

Comment: Thanks Shai Rado!

Comment: place your loop right above your next ws, also your edit invalidated your question, please revert it.

Comment: Also you want to post your `i=i+1` right before your Loop. Now you find a match, increment the value of i, and then copy over the row.

Comment: I'd like to thank you all for your valuable comments. Everything is runs smoothly now.